# Integration of multiplication of normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, normal-distribution

Assume we have three random variables X, Y, Z in which Y and Z are independent. What is the result of this integration ($N$ represents normal distribution over random variable with mean and variance)
$$\int_Z\int_{Y} N(X|Y-Z,1)  N(Z|\mu_z,\sigma_z^2)N(Y|\mu_y,\sigma_y^2) dydz$$
I know that $\int_{Y} N(X|Y,1) N(Y|\mu_y,\sigma_y^2) dy = N(X|\mu_y,\sigma_y+1)$ But the inclusion of Z into formula as $ N(X|Y-Z,1)$ makes this problem unsolvable for me.

Comment: Using *Mathematica* and $N(X|Y-Z,\sigma_x^2)$ rather than $N(X|Y-Z,1)$ the result is $\frac{e^{-\frac{\left(X-\mu _y+\mu _z\right){}^2}{2 \left(\sigma _x^2+\sigma _y^2+\sigma _z^2\right)}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\sigma _x^2+\sigma _y^2+\sigma _z^2}}$. Unfortunately, the use of Rubi in *Mathematica* does not give a result and therefore none of the steps to get the result.

Comment: Could you provide me the Mathematica script?

Comment: @JimB I tried Integrate[Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[Y-Z,Subscript[\[Sigma],x]^2],X]*PDF[NormalDistribution[Subscript[\[Mu],y] ,Subscript[\[Sigma],y]^2],Y]*PDF[NormalDistribution[Subscript[\[Mu],z] ,Subscript[\[Sigma],z]^2],Z] ,Y],Z] but did not give me a proper result

Comment: My guess as to why things didn't work is that you used two instances of `Integrate` rather than just one and did not use `Assumptions` to restrict the standard deviations to be greater than zero.  Also, that code produces (or attempts to produce) an indefinite integral rather than a definite integral. And (there's more!) *Mathematica*'s `NormalDistribution` needs the standard deviation rather than the variance.

Comment: Thank you I haven't used Mathematica before but it would be really nice to get intermediate steps since still I do not understand how it ended up with that result.

Comment: I think the steps are (1) expanding the exponent terms (2) completing the square for the $y$ terms, (3) integrating over $y$, (4) completing the square for the $z$ terms, and then (4) integrating over$z$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but just an extended comment to give the associated *Mathematica* code.

```
result = Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[y - z, σx], X]* 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[μz, σz], z]*PDF[NormalDistribution[μy, σy], y],
  {z, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {σx > 0, σy > 0, σz > 0}]
```

[image: Result of integration]

One can make this look in a more usual form:

```
result /. {σx -> Subscript[σ, x], σy -> Subscript[σ, y], σz -> Subscript[σ, z],
 μy -> Subscript[μ, y], μz -> Subscript[μ, z]}
```

[image: Result]